# SCSS style got purged with @nuxtjs/tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, css-purge

I've got a nuxt project where I use **@nuxtjs/tailwindcss** and **vue-formulate**. I've declared a few styles for **vue-formulate** in a scss file and it works great when I do `nuxt --spa` but when I try to generate the project using `nuxt generate` and serve it, the style does not apply at all. I've done a few tests and it seems to be coming from **@nuxtjs/tailwindcss**. When I remove it from `buildModules` in my nuxt config, it works fine. How can I keep that style without having to remove the purgecss step?

Answer (score 1):

take a look for whitelisting the classes that "vue-formulate" are using.

[purge css whitelisting](https://purgecss.com/whitelisting.html)

Comment: I tried whitelisting those classes by wrapping them with `/* purgecss start/end ignore */` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Updating nuxt and @nuxt/tailwindcss fixed the issue.